# Why does bootstrap have two fonts in Sass?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, sass

I was just about to change the default font with Bootstrap SASS and I found this:

```
//== Typography
//
//## Font, line-height, and color for body text, headings, and more.

$font-family-sans-serif:  "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !default;
$font-family-serif:       Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !default;
```

What's the difference between sans-serif and serif in this context? Because if I inspect my page, all fonts are Helvetica Neue.

How is serif/Georgia utilised if all I'm seeing is Helvetica Neue being used?

Comment: when the font family for the base is serif? ..... they are there just as an option to change between serif and sans-serif

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'base'? When would it ever change between serif and sans-serif?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are just options to change the `base` style for the font so if you want serif or sans-serif. They do this:

Create the three base styles:

> $font-family-sans-serif:  "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !default; 
>   $font-family-serif:       Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !default;
>   $font-family-monospace:   Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Courier New", monospace !default;

Then set the `sans-serif` on a base var:

> $font-family-base:        $font-family-sans-serif !default;

And use that base to define the font-family for the `body` therefore all the document:

> ```
> body {
>    font-family: $font-family-base;
>    font-size: $font-size-base;
>    line-height: $line-height-base;
>    color: $text-color;
>    background-color: $body-bg;
> }
> ```

---

The other options are there if you want to customize the theme and change quickly to serif or monospace all the document.

Comment: Another thing, why are some font names wrapped in " " and some aren't?

Comment: @ProEvilz if the name of the font has spaces needs to be quoted